# Webpack: вариативное использование лоадеров

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

Существует некий набор картинок svg, которые я желаю вставлять с помощью inline-svg-loader на страницу (предположим, там будет интерактивность), для чего пишу:

```
          test: /\.svg$/,
          use: [
              'svg-inline-loader'
          ]
```

---

Существует некий набор фонов для элементов, которые я желаю вставить в css и обрабатывать их через file-loader. Однако svg уже обрабатывается другим лоадером.

---

Можно ли реализовать вариативность использования лоадеров в зависимости от ситуации?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перемести .svg файлы в разные папки, например fonts/ и images/. В поле `test` просто используй регулярные выражения `images[\S]*\.svg$` и `fonts[\S]*\.svg$` или что-то похожее.